# what is the name of Numeric library by Microsoft?

Tags: c#, .net

i have a little problem . There are some Numerical analyze program on web for .NET. But i see 2 or 3 months ago. But i don't remember name of this library. Microsoft Solution founder or
Microsoft Solutions? Can you give me name of this numeric library by Microsoft?

Comment: "Numeric library" is vague. Please tell us exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: By the time you finish keying in `Microsoft Sol` google's autocomplete has the answer for you.

Comment: @GregC: I think tags are not meant to be used to answer a question.

Comment: +1 legitimate question, wish I could vote against close votes. It's annoying to see speakers who use English as a second language have their questions frequently shot at instead of effort being put in to improve the wording of the question.... **edit** Voting to reopen.

Comment: I didn't close it because of his English (it's not that bad), but because this isn't actually a "real question".

Comment: @Chris: someone can understand my question " But i don't remember name of this library. Microsoft Solution founder or Microsoft Solutions? " is clear for  normal intelligence

Comment: @John Saunders I think knowing a library exists but not being able to recall the library exactly and seeking guidance on what the library actually is, seems to be a pretty direct question. Especially when you see the answer has been provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Microsoft Solver Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/hh145003.aspx)